# Data synchronization of local sdf and SQL Server through Sync Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, windows-phone-7, sql-server-ce, microsoft-sync-framework

I have a Windows phone 7 application that uses a local storage file (`.sdf`) to save data.
I need to synchronize that data with the SQL Server database so they can be viewed and edited from the website as well.

I have checked the examples from the Sync Framework but my problem is that no example used an `.sdf` file to synchronize the data.

Also the ViewModel of the local database on the windows phone is like this:

```
public class ADataContext : DataContext
{
            // Pass the connection string to the base class.
            public ADataContext (string connectionString)
                : base(connectionString)
            { }

            // Specify a table for the lists
            public Table<Lists> Lists;

        }

        [Index(Columns = "ListName", Name = "_listNameUnique", IsUnique = true)]
        [Table]
        public class Lists : INotifyPropertyChanged, INotifyPropertyChanging
        {

            // Define ID: private field, public property, and database column.
            private int _id;

            [Column(DbType = "INT NOT NULL IDENTITY", IsDbGenerated = true, IsPrimaryKey = true)]
            public int Id
            {
                get { return _id; }
                set
                {
                    NotifyPropertyChanging("Id");
                    _id = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("Id");
                }
            }
}
```

Is there a way to synchronize this local database (`.sdf`) with their matching tables in the SQL Server database by using the Sync Framework or will I have to do the synchronization manually?

If I have to do it manually what would be an optimized method for doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far a I know, the current release of the MS Sync Framework does not support SQL Server CE 4 on the phone.

So you're probably on your own for now - check out [Erik EJ's Everything SQL Server Compact](http://erikej.blogspot.com/) site - he has tons of good material, code samples, tools and so forth.

He also has a [page specifically dedicated to SQL Server CE on the Windows phone](http://erikej.blogspot.com/2011/07/windows-phone-sql-server-compact.html).

Answer (score 0):

have you looked at the [Sync Framework Toolkit](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Sync-Framework-Toolkit-4dc10f0e)? I think there's 2 sample providers for SDF in there under WM6.5 that works with SQL CE and that you can retrofit to work with WP7.

or if you want to code it yourself, have a look at the approach here: [Synchronizing Data between the Phone and the Cloud](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh821017.aspx).

Comment: the WP7 example is very clear since all the code is being generated by the Sync Framework tool. I have seen those examples before as well but the problem is that i cant figure exactly how this works and i don't find it a good idea seen from what i have seen on the code i have to implement almost everything. So why use the framework from the first place when i have to do the work?

Comment: depends how you look at it...if you're fine coding yourself the change tracking, change enumeration, change application, conflict handling and recording what has been synched, then you might want to go that way... if you look at the toolkit, those things are part of the framework, you just have to handle client provider part.